# cd into the directory of found file used with dir

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am in need of some help with my CMD script.
Currently what I'm doing is searching for a specific file with:

```
cd ../cache
dir /s "filename.exe
```

when CMD finds that file it outputs this:

"Directory of C:Windows\system32\cache\folder\thefileImlookingfor"

what I'd like to do now, after CMD has found the file, is to "cd" into that directory where I found said file. HOWEVER, the folder that's just called folder for this instance, changes names from time to time. But that should not matter since the file name is still the same. So how can I "cd" to the directory of the filename that I've found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a `for` loop for that:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s "filename.exe"') do cd /d "%%~dpi"
```

Alternatively using `pushd`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s "filename.exe"') do pushd "%%~dpi"
echo do some things here..
popd
```

To understand better what happens here, open `cmd` and run `for /?`. Specifically focus on substitution of `for` variable references

Comment: I realise I'm awfully late, but that's exactly what I needed :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I understood in your question suggests using `For /D /R "C:\Path\To\Folder"`

```
@echo off

for /d /r ..\back %%G in (*)do if exist "%%G\filename.exe" cd/d "%%G"
```

> *[The option `/d /r` is undocumented, but can be a
>
> useful combination, while it will recurse through all  subfolders the wildcard will only match against
>
> Folder/Directory names (not filenames).](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)*
>
> *[Period/Full Stop
> Although Win32 will not recognise any file or directory name that begins or ends with a `'.'` (period / full stop) it is possible to include a Full Stop in the middle of a directory name and this can cause issues with `FOR /D`.](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)*
>
> *[Parameter expansion will treat a Full Stop as a file extension, so for a directory name like `"Sample 2.6.4"` the output of `%%~nG` will be truncated to `"Sample 2.6"` to return the whole folder name use `%%G` or `%%~nxG`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)*
>
> - Source: **[ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**